# How to create a RAID device with specifying a size ?

Tags: linux, partition, hard-disk, raid, storage

I want to Create a RAID 0 array using the two partitions /dev/sda2 & /dev/sda3 (They are both of size 3G each)

The properties of the array is the following:

```
1. SIZE = 2048MB
2. Label=RAID_0
3. Mount it persistently by label at /storage
```

So here is my attempt to do it. Me logged as root I executed the following commands.

```
# mdadm -C -v /dev/md0 –size=1024M –level=stripe –raid-devices=2   
/dev/sda3 /dev/sda4

# mdadm –detail /dev/md0
# mkfs -t ext4  -L RAID_0   /dev/md0
# mdadm – detail –scan > /etc/mdadm.conf
# mdadm –assemble –scan
# mkdir /storage
# vi /etc/fstab
LABEL=RAID_0        /storage        ext4        defaults        0   0
# systemctl enable mdmonitor
# systemctl start mdmonitor
```

Everything executed successfully, My question is now. Is my 1st command correct ? I want the size of the array to be 2048M so I divide that by 2 because am using two partitions ? Is that correct.

Comment: As you have just done it, why don't you just look at the result?

Comment: When I did execute 

#lsblk 

It seems what I did is right